# I cannot move an image, what should I do?

Tags: html, css, image, github, github-pages

I am trying to move an image (map.png), but I cannot move it.

My HTML code is:

```
<div class="map">      
    <h3 style="text-align:right;" >
    <img src="img/map.png" alt="">
    </h3>
    </div>
```

My CSS code is:

```
.map {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
}
```

I have a GitHub repository at:
https://github.com/t0091/bootstrap

Comment: Where are you tying to move the image? Do you want the image on the right side of the document? Or do you want the image 25 pixels front the left of the document?

Comment: Why do you have the img wrapped in an `<h3>`? And why is that h3 aligned right? Does the image overflow the div? If the image is larger than the container (div) then moving the container a bit might not move the image. Also you have an extra closing `</div>` tag in your snippet.

Comment: @twomarktwo I am trying to move the image up, not left, I just put that there to make it easier for me too see if it moved.

Comment: @gibberish I did that to align the image.

Comment: @TylerWolf DevTools (F12) is your best friend for solving this kind of problem. If you aren't comfortable using it, then learning that should be your first priority. Stefan Joseph's answer is a good one ( +1 ) - Flexbox and CSSGrid are the easiest ways to align HTML elements. Flexbox is easy *and it works.* But DevTools... watch all the video tutorials you can on this subject. You will thank yourself later.

Answer (score 1):

I am still not sure what you are actually trying to achieve. Howerver I have taken you code and re-written it in a way where your image is centered vertically and horizontally. You can add any css you want in the `.image-content` class.

HTML

```
<div class="flex-display">
<div class="image-content">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt=""> //Use you correct image path
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.flex-display {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.image-content {
  // Write your image styling here if needed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your picture is in the correct directory and the file type is correct. To center the image and make sure it is appearing somewhere on your webpage you can add this css

```
.map {
   display: block;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   width: 50%;
}
```

If after trying this it still does not work then it has to be something specific with the image. Make sure the image is spelled the same in your code, cameCase matters!
Also, verify the file path is correct as well as the filetype. You could also try adding a '/' before /img/map.png

Lastly, here is a resource that explains HTML/CSS images work. [HTML IMAGES](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp)

Comment: I have tried that, it was centered but not vertically, on horizontally. I even added the line "top: 100px" (to test if it went up) but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.map {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

According to the above solution, you only need to use **margin-top** instead of margin and according to below one just change the **position**.

```css
.map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
}
```